# MySQL Selecting where datetime column =

Tags: mysql

Hi I am trying to get the following sql to work in mysql but it always return an empty result set - however there are definitely entries that match the criteria.
I'm new to mySQl so would appreciate if someone could point out where I am going wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM  `ch_results` 
WHERE  'readingDateTime' =  '2011-03-29 20:00:00'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the field name:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `ch_results` 
WHERE   readingDateTime =  '2011-03-29 20:00:00'
```

Your current query compares string `'readingDateTime'` to another string, `'2011-03-29 20:00:00'`, which comparison of course never holds true.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the quotes on the 'readingDateTime'. This is comparing strings to each other.

```
WHERE  readingDateTime =  '2011-03-29 20:00:00'
```